# Reaction to messages not working (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted the bot to react to the message if it's sent by a certain author.

**Code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == '356268235697553409':
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')
```

I tried this but it didn't work, it didn't even show any errors, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you even verified that the program enters that `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`discord.Member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.id) returns you a `int` type value. That means that you cannot compare a `str` value to a `discord.Member.id` value. You just have to do:

```py
if message.author.id == 356268235697553409:
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's are always integers, you're comparing an int to a string, to fix it:

```py
if message.author.id == 356268235697553409:
    # ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but that, unfortunately, did not work.

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as other users have already mentioned, you cannot compare an `int` to a `string.` The correct syntax would be:

```
if message.author.id == 356268235697553409:
    # Rest of your code here
```

Secondly, what you are doing is overriding the default provided `on_message` command. This forbids any commands from running, which might be the root cause of your issue. The correct way of using `on_message` would be adding the following like to the end of your `on_message`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Your code
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Alternatively, you an place your `on_message` logic into a listener (without the need of manually calling `bot.process_commands()`. This is done to allow multiple asynchronous actions in response to a message. Example:

```
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def whatever_you_want_to_call_it(message):
    # do stuff here
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing, unfortunately. :-/